# How to programmatically retrieve the connection string from an Azure storage account in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

Suppose that you have admin access and you have just created a storage account programmatically in a Python script.

How can you then retrieve a connection string from that newly created storage account in Python? For example, if you wanted to create Storage Queues within the same script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [azure-mgmt-storage](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-storage/) to create the storage account, then you can follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-storage?tabs=cmd#3-write-code-to-provision-storage-resources) to fetch the connection string.

Here is the code snippet in the sample above to fetch connection string:

```
# Step 3: Retrieve the account's primary access key and generate a connection string.
keys = storage_client.storage_accounts.list_keys(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)

print(f"Primary key for storage account: {keys.keys[0].value}")

conn_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName={STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME};AccountKey={keys.keys[0].value}"

print(f"Connection string: {conn_string}")
```

Comment: Extremely helpful, thanks! Would also recommend that people review the article to see how to wait for storage account provisioning to complete before querying for the connection string.